# Creating Folders with Foreach Loop Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: c#, foreach, directory

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Transfer
Transfer\Classified
Transfer\Keys
Transfer\Container
Transfer
```

I read the contents of the text file into a collection and use a `for each` loop to create the directories, like this:

```
BindingList<string> listFolders = new BindingList<string>();

foreach(string dirCreate in listFolders)
{
    try
    {
        if(!Directory.Exists(dirCreate)){

            Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Concat(txtRootFolder.Text,"\\",dirCreate));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} already exists",dirCreate));
        }

    }
    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
    }
```

**Problem:** If a directory already exists, the MessageBox will pop up twice, what I mean is, It will pop up once saying directory already exists, the user clicks okay, and it will pop up again, making the user click okay again. How do I make it only pop up once?

Comment: Well, you do have the same directory "Transfer" in your text file twice.  Why not remove the second one?

Comment: @juharr - I was running a test to make sure that the if statement works, and it does, only the `messagebox` pops up twice.

Comment: Sure the message box pops up twice if you have got "Transfer" twice, what are you even expecting??

Comment: I only want it to pop up once telling the user it already exists

Comment: You could do a `Distinct` on your `listFolders` but really there's no need for it to be in there twice.

Comment: Does that "Transfer" directory exist _before_ the test run?  The for loop would see it twice and show the messagebox twice.

Comment: @Jeffdot-No, I delete the Transfer folder each time the test is run

Comment: I don't see how you'd get the message box twice if you have deleted the "Transfer" folder before running.  What do you see if you debug and step through the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I directly see an error in your code.

for the check, don't you think that you have to add the entire path, and not just the partial path?

This:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(dirCreate)){
```

should be:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(String.Concat(txtRootFolder.Text,"\\",dirCreate))){
```

When I did the above in my console application, the output was like this;

[image: output]

Hope this helps.

[UPDATE] WPF Code behind;

```
        BindingList<string> paths;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            paths = new BindingList<string>();
            paths.Add(@"Transfer");
            paths.Add(@"Transfer\Classified");
            paths.Add(@"Transfer\Keys");
            paths.Add(@"Transfer\Container");
            paths.Add(@"Transfer");
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string dirCreate in paths)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(String.Concat(txtFolderPath.Text, "\\", dirCreate)))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Concat(txtFolderPath.Text, "\\", dirCreate));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} already exists", dirCreate));
                    }

                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException msg)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

But still cannot reproduce the issue.

[UPDATE 2] Code for WinForm

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<string> paths;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        paths = new BindingList<string>();
        paths.Add(@"Transfer");
        paths.Add(@"Transfer\Classified");
        paths.Add(@"Transfer\Keys");
        paths.Add(@"Transfer\Container");
        paths.Add(@"Transfer");
    }

    private void btnCreateFolders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string dirCreate in paths)
        {
            try
            {
                string strDirectoryName = String.Concat(txtFolderPath.Text, "\\", dirCreate);

                if (!Directory.Exists(strDirectoryName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectoryName);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} already exists", dirCreate));
                }

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException msg)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Still cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: It will treat them as relative paths from the current working directory.

Comment: Can you please provide more info on what you are doing after this try-catch block?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarN - Just display it in a listbox

Comment: I'm using a WinForm as well, so if you can replicate it using that, would be great.

Comment: I used WPF to replicate it. Unfortunately couldn't replicate it.

Comment: Could you try a win form, you're doing everything I am.

Comment: Ok.. will try that as well.

Comment: No Luck mate. updating the code for WinForm. By the way I am trying these things out in .NET Framework 4.6.

Comment: Same here, thanks for trying, I'll compare the code you put

Comment: AHHHHH! I got it, I modified it, so that the directory name is stored in a string variable like you did, and then test to see if it exist, it works! Update two is the correct one. Not sure why switching to a string variable works, but it does.